# How do i print the corresponding integer value of binary number to its place? (in python)

Tags: python, binary, integer

I want to find the corresponding integer value of a binary number, but to its place value. What I mean is for example: **if the binary number is 1111 , I need to print 8,4,2,1.**

Example2: **11011**, output should be **16,8,2,1.**

I am new to programing. I can't figure out the logic. Please help. Thanks.

```
n=(bin(int(input("enter number: "))))#i need to find the corresponding place values .
print(n)
```

I can't seem to figure out the logic.

Comment: hi, this looks like a homework assignment..
Are there constraints on how long the binary number can be, or is it arbitrary?
In any case, generating the powers of 2 in a reverse-sorted list up untill the length of the gotten binary string should work as a good first idea to help you along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you can understand it

```
n=(bin(int(input("enter number: "))))#i need to find the corresponding place values .

#list to store the binary number separated by each digit
nl = [] 

#A For loop to remove the '0b' in variable n
for i in range(len(n)): 
    if i!=0 and i!=1:
        nl.append(n[i])
    
nl.reverse()

#list to store the answer
al = []

#A for loop to create integer value of each digit
for i in range(len(nl)):
    if nl[i] =='1':
        al.append(2**i)
        
al.reverse()

print(al)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work out the highest power of two in the number by taking its base 2 logarithm.  Given this information, keep subtracting successive powers of two from the number as long as the result foes not go below zero.

```py
>>> import math
>>>
>>> parts = []
>>> b = 0b11011
>>> for i in range(int(math.log(b, 2)), -1, -1):
...     c = 2 ** i
...     if (b - c) >= 0:
...         b -= c
...         parts.append(c)
... 
>>> parts
[16, 8, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
bin_num=bin(11011)

# Convert the binary number to int
int_num = int(bin_num, 2)

# Variable to store the results
text_bin = ""
for ind, character in enumerate(str(int_num)):
    # Get position
    pos = len(str(int_num))-ind-1
    # Suffix
    suffix=","
    if pos==0:
        suffix=""
    # Record position when 1
    if character=="1":
        text_bin+=str(2**pos)+suffix
        
print(text_bin)
```

Output:

```
16,8,2,1
```